# F10 key not working in terminal/MC, Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, midnight-commander

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 desktop, trying to use terminal and `mc`. The <kbd>F10</kbd> key shortcut to quit MC is not working, nothing happens, only the cursor blinks when I press <kbd>F10</kbd>. I tried some ideas about this I found on the internet, but couldn't solve the problem. Running `showkey` from command line, I can see `key 68 press` and release when I press <kbd>F10</kbd>.

I'm out of ideas on how solve this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What terminal do you use? Do other F keys work fine? Have you tried other terminals? Does it work in virtual console (TTY)?

Comment: I use the Ubuntu default gnome terminal. I just tried KDE Konsole and it's the same. Other F keys work fine. In virtual console, F10 works.

Answer (score 14):

In Terminal: Preferences -> General F10 was bound to "Menu accelerator"

[image]

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 6):

If the function keys do not work, use the following alternatives:

[image]

Source: https://youtu.be/rddUniuHuWM?t=46

Comment: Thanks, the Alt+0 did not work, but the Esc+0 is working perfectly. Thank you for the simple solution for a long lasting problem!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to disable <kbd>F10</kbd> key is to use `gsettings` from the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings menu-accelerator-enabled false
```

It does exactly the same thing as [Edgar's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1626923/1729923), but from the command line.